# How to replace series of delimeter with the specific text

Tags: java

call to method:

String Text = "Test Cash. deposit for an  account % of currency  %";

String Token = "12345|USD";

String parsedText = parseText(Text, Token);

private static String parseText(String text, String tokens) {

```
    String textDelimiter = text.trim().replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9_.]", "");

    String tokenDelimiter = tokens.trim().replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9_.]", "");

    String[] tokenSplit = tokens.split(tokenDelimiter);

    String[] textSplit = text.split(textDelimiter);

    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < textSplit.length; i++) {

        result += textSplit[i] + tokenSplit[i];
    }

    System.out.println(result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code you have attempted?

Comment: See my answer for unknown numbers of token. Some test need to be added to prevent an exception if you are not sure of the values.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing the correct size of the arrays, this could be a hint:

```
private String parseText(String text, String tokens, String textDelimiter, String tokenDelimiter){
    String[] tokenSplit = tokens.split(tokenDelimiter);
    String[] textSplit = text.split(textDelimiter);

    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <textSplit.length; i++){
        result += textSplit[i] + tokenSplit[i];
    }
    System.out.println(result);

    return result;
}
```

And the call:

```
String Text="Test Cash deposit for an  account % of currency  %"; 
String Token="12345|USD";

String parsedText = parseText(Text, Token, "%", "\\|");
```

Comment: Token delimeter  is  dynamic , depends on the future requirements  it can be anything

Comment: tokens can be more than 2 also

Comment: Then you can pass the delimiter in the method arguments.
This method work with more than 2 tokens

Comment: i am not getting the expected output ,plz assist

Comment: I do, how do you cal this method?

Comment: As of now im just creating object and calling the method by passing the values

Comment: Do you call the method with '\\' before the '|' char ? (As I edited in the answer)

Comment: String Text="Test Cash deposit for an  account % of currency  %"; 
    String Token="12345|USD";
    String textDelimiter="%";
    String tokenDelimiter="|";

    String parsedText = parseText(Text, Token, textDelimiter,tokenDelimiter);

Comment: scenerio where i dont want to pass the text and token delimeter in the method , instead only text and token need to pass and it has to pick the delimeter from that text and do the replacement

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change the format of `Text` and `Token` you could do it that way

```
String format = "Test Cash deposit for an  account %s of currency  %s";
String[] tokens = {"12345","USD"};
String amended = String.format(format, tokens[0], tokens[1]);
System.out.println(amended);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `String.format(..)` method, for example:

```
String output = String.format("Test Cash deposit for an  account %s of currency  %s","12345","USD");
```

Comment: private static void parseText(String text, String tokens)
   {
      if (tokens != null)
      {
         final String regex = "[%]+";
         text = text.replaceAll(regex, "%s");
         System.out.println(String.format(text, (Object[])tokens.split(regex)));
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String Text = "Test Cash. deposit for an  account A/C % fdjf %";
      String Token = "12345";
      parseText(Text, Token);

   }

Comment: this will give me java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException,,, can anybody suggest how to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String Text="Test Cash deposit for an  account %d of currency  %s";
String[] Tokens="12345|USD".split("\\|");
System.out.printf(Text, Integer.valueOf(Tokens[0]), Tokens[1]);
```

Comment: private static void parseText(String text, String tokens) { if (tokens != null) { final String regex = "[%]+"; text = text.replaceAll(regex, "%s"); System.out.println(String.format(text, (Object[])tokens.split(regex))); } } public static void main(String[] args) { String Text = "Test Cash. deposit for an account A/C % fdjf %"; String Token = "12345"; parseText(Text, Token); }        Can anybody suggest solution for this

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic tokens, just create a method :

```
public String convert(String text, String value){
    return String.format("test", value.split("\\|")
);
```

You just have to call it to convert every '%s' in the text with the parameter received :

```
String Text="Test Cash deposit for an  account %s of currency  %s"; 
String Token="12345|USD";
System.out.println(convert(Text, Token));
```

You can use it directly as :

```
System.out.println(
     String.format(
         "Test Cash deposit for an  account %s of currency  %s", 
         (Object[]) "12345|USD".split("\\|"))); //Casting to remove the warning, not sure if one Object or a var-args. Cast in array to use var-args
```

but this is not really nice ;)

You are going to be sure that the number of %s is greater or equals than the number of tokens received, if not you are going to end up with an exception (to many argument).

EDIT :

For a version without knowing the specifc delimiter for both String : (using not [a-zA-z0-9._ ]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    parseText("test % to % or #", "5+8^test"); //test 5 to 8 or test
}

private static void parseText(String text, String tokens) {
    String regex = "[^\\w. ]+"; // \w = alphanumeric + _ 
    text = text.replaceAll(regex, "%s");
    System.out.println(String.format(text, (Object[]) tokens.split(regex)));
}
```

Comment: scenerio where i dont want to pass the text and token delimeter in the method , instead only text and token need to pass and it has to pick the delimeter from that text and do the replacement

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: call the method by passing 2 parameters i.e text and token .
after calling split the token and text delimeter and store it in variable, delimeter can be anything except [A-Za-z][0-9][.]

Comment: String[] tokenSplit = tokens.split(tokenDelimiter);
     String[] textSplit = text.split(textDelimiter);

     String result = "";
     for (int i = 0; i <textSplit.length; i++){
         result += textSplit[i] + tokenSplit[i];
     }
     System.out.println(result);

     return result;
 }

Comment: Why do you want to split both of them ? You can split with a regex to have the correct array of token. If your text use the correct tag `%s`, leave it like this. If not, you should have ask your question better.

Comment: i want to split to get the delimeter , becoz those delimeter are not constant they can be anything ...

Comment: private static String parseText(String text, String tokens){
 
  String textDelimiter=text.trim().replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9_.]", "");
  String tokenDelimiter=tokens.trim().replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9_.]", "");
  
   String[] tokenSplit = tokens.split(tokenDelimiter);
         String[] textSplit = text.split(textDelimiter);

         String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <textSplit.length; i++){
         result += textSplit[i] + tokenSplit[i];
     }
     System.out.println(result);

     return result;
 }

Comment: i tried doing this way but didnt worked .. my call   will be   ..String Text="Test Cash. deposit for an  account % of currency  %"; 
    String Token="12345|USD";
    String parsedText = parseText(Text, Token);

Comment: Which ones, those for the token or the text ? Update your question to add **every informations** you didn't put at the beginning... the format for both text and tokens you can receive, the output expected. Your code could work with a bit of update but this is a bit execive.